# Drools Temporal Rules

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I'm newbie to the Drools. Here i'm trying to generate a notification if a process is running for longer than some time - let's say 5 minutes.

To achieve the above I'm writing the following code in DRL file. But it doesn't seem to be working.

### drl file

```
declare Message
  @role(event) 
end 

rule "RULE 3" 
 when
   $message: Message(msgtext == "1st message") over window:time( 5m ) from entry-point entryone
 then
    System.out.println("RULE 3 (after 5 min of message event started): " +     $message.getMsgtext());
 end
```

In the above `.drl` file I have an event named `Message` declared. The rule is checking whether `msgtext` is `1st message` and it is running for 5 minutes - if that's the case, I have to generate a notification. In this example I'm just printing the result.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check,

- Put your entry point name in quotes
- Does it work without the time constraint (i.e. only message:
  Message(msgtext == "1st message")
- Note, this is checking to see if the message "1st message" has been
  added within the last 5 minutes
- Make sure you're in stream mode

-hth

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I've passed this problem by using timer(int:5m) instead of window sliding.